# Position SVG lines over HTML elements, while still allowing interaction with the HTMl elements

Tags: html, css, svg

Given the following Codesnippet:

```css
.html {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.svg {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="html">
    <p title="Title Text" onclick="console.log('clicked')">
      Some text
    </p>

    <svg class="svg">
          <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="200" stroke="blue" stroke-width="10"></line>
        </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

(See http://jsfiddle.net/5phzgxLa/)

I would like to have the SVG `line` be drawn over the `p` element within the HTML, while still being able to fully interact with the HTML (the title text should still display on hover, and the `onclick` handler should still fire on clicking the text).

I can change the HTML and CSS in any way needed to do this, but I do need the SVG to be `fixed` over the HTML, as I essentially want an SVG layer I can draw things on over normal HTML, with the SVG layer moving as the page is scrolled.

Is this possible? If not, is there any way to achieve a similar effect?

Comment: give the SVG line the pointer-events: none; CSS property.

Comment: @RobertLongson that works, and easier than expected, thanks! If you add this as an answer I'll accept it.